# Set<> Only retaining Last Folder Values

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using the below code to generate a list of folders and files in the folders, and I want to get a list of unique extensions.  By extensions, I classify anything after the last "." in a file string.  I have the below code which will produce a full list of folder structure, but seems to only produce the extensions for the last directory iterated.

How do I remedy that, so that all extensions are added to my list?

```
   Set<String> getExt;

public void showFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {            
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
            showFiles(file.listFiles()); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
            getExt = new HashSet<String>();
            for (File f: files) {
              getExt.add(f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You `getExt = new HashSet<String>();`, creates new `HashSet`, overwriting old contents

Comment: Without taking a close look I would guess it's because of `getExt = new HashSet<String>();` being **inside** the loop. So you're probably re-assigning it every iteration with a fresh new empty set.

Comment: As well as moving `getExt = new HashSet<String>()` outside of the loop, as others have suggested, you don't need a second loop inside the `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep creating a new `HashSet` inside the loop, which discards the previous one.  Change the declaration of `getExt` to:

```
Set<String> getExt = new HashSet<String>();
```

then remove

```
        getExt = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: I get an error of Diamond operator is not supported in 1.6

Comment: Then either use a newer version than 1.6, or don't use the diamond operator.

Comment: Java 1.6 is ancient, you should upgrade to at least 1.8.